# What is the Class.extend({}); code in the following javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I don't understand the following code. What is the Class.extend() and what does it do?
It's from an HTML development atlas loading tutorial on Udacity.

```
var gSpriteSheets = {};

//-----------------------------------------
SpriteSheetClass = Class.extend({

// We store in the SpriteSheetClass:
//
// The Image object that we created for our
// atlas.
img: null,

// The URL path that we grabbed our atlas
// from.
url: "",

// An array of all the sprites in our atlas.
sprites: [],

//-----------------------------------------
init: function () {},

//-----------------------------------------
// Load the atlas at the path 'imgName' into
// memory. This is similar to how we've
// loaded images in previous units.
load: function (imgName) {
    // Store the URL of the spritesheet we want.
    this.url = imgName;
........
```

The rest is insignificant.

Comment: We could probably make a decent educated guess based on the name of the object and function, but you haven't shown us the code for `Class.extend` so we can't say for sure.

Comment: Why Udacity doesn't use pure js? They use a library? I didn't know that I'll check it out. And I just want to know what Class.extend does. Does it like add methods to an object or something?

Comment: @RamiAwar Looking at the course transcript, `Class.extend` is based on John Resig's (creator of jQuery) blog post for [Simple Javascript Inheritance](http://ejohn.org/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). The link shows the implementation and some explanation for this. I agree using this in a JS introduction course without some internal details isn't overly helpful

Comment: Man i had come across this link a thousand times now and I never thought of checking the core.js file... Thanks a bunch though i figured it out :D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out the Class object is defined in the core.js, another file alongside the working file on Udacity.

The code is probably based on a blog post by John Resig, [Simple JavaScript Inheritance](https://johnresig.com/blog/simple-javascript-inheritance/). It is a simple, re-usable way to implement "classical" (or "object-oriented, as opposed to "prototype-based") inheritance in Javascript.